# Excel How to assign a letter a specific number value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on a PTO spreadsheet. We have 3 types of days (V)vacation, (P}Personal and (H)Holiday. I want to assign a number value to each of those letters, so that every time one is put into the calendar it subtracts from a starting total.

For instance.. V=12hrs.Employee starts with 120hrs, and every V placed on calendar subtracts 12 from that total.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show what work you have already done. That is, upload images or a file of how you currently have your spreadsheet set up and what work you have already done toward a solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . I assume you want this calculation to be done in a total cell of how much time still left or something like that. But in order to properly answer this we would need to see how your sheet is structured (where the data is answered and where you expect the total/s etc.) So please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1793780/edit) and add a sample of your spreadsheet and what you expect where

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added a snip. The starting balance will be added manually, I'd like to be able to place a letter on a date and it subtract from thr starting balance and show in the remaining balance. V=12hrs, P and H =1 day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**COUNTIF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) will do most of the work for you.

Simply count how many times the designation from column **D** appears in the range `G10:CW16` and subtract that value from column **C** (multiply by 12 in the case of **V**).
So, in cells E10:E12 you will get formulas

```
=C10-COUNTIF(G10:CW16,D10)*12
=C11-COUNTIF(G10:CW16,D11)
=C12-COUNTIF(G10:CW16,D12)
```

Now just copy and paste these cells for each of the employees.